# When FlowDirection/UICulture is right-to-Left, the window SizeToContent "WidthAndHeight" is still sizing to the left

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, right-to-left, sizetocontent

While working on localizing my WPF-c# app for Right-to-Left language (=RTL, In my case it's hebrew) -
I have come around a problem I can't find any reference on anywhere on MSDN or google and therefore no answer. Needless to say I'm new to programming...

My code is a bit long so I'll try and explain the main problem in words.

In my app, I have a window (not a MainWindow) containing a `StackPanel`. Inside I've nested a `TabControl` with 3 tab items, each of them containing a different `UserControl` I've pointing to. Each one of them has a different size.

On the same window I set the Window property `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"`.
The app works great while on the default Left-to-right setting, and when
I change the `FlowDirection` in c# (also tried in XAML) to right to left it also works OK except of this:

When starting the app and moving between the tabs, the window is resizing, BUT it keeps sizing the window to the top-left position. I.e the top left stays anchored in place while the rest of the window sizes according to the content (this is great when working in `LeftToRight` UI but it's annoying and hard to use on RTL UI because the tabs headers keep moving).

**Is there a way to change the window's sizing direction so that on RTL UI the window will size toward the top-right?** Am I doing something wrong?